# Cleos cannot find contract directory

Tags: smart-contract, cleos

I am trying the get started guide but I get stuck in the hello world smart contract. Here is the console log.

```
root@d75d5dde1190:/home/savvas/EOS/contracts/hello# ls
hello.abi  hello.cpp  hello.wasm  hello.wast  hello.wast.abi


root@d75d5dde1190:/home/savvas/EOS/contracts# cleos set contract /home/savvas/EOS/contracts/hello --abi hello.abi -p hello@active
Error 3160000: Contract exception
Error Details:
 contract-dir is null
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK seems that the problem is that I didn't provide contract name. Changing the command to 
`cleos set contract hello /home/savvas/EOS/contracts/hello --abi hello.abi -p hello@active` solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Just to add, `hello` after `set contract` is the account name which has been created to dedicate the contract. Usually practice is to keep the name of such accounts same as contract name.